# How to convert RTF to android spannable?

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring

Is there a way to convert a text in RTF format to android SpannableString? 
I would like to display an RTF text in a TextView.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to write custom RTFEditor class for saving RTF in textview. Java swing has property to convert but android doesn't support swing.